# sbt error: object spark is not a member of package org.apache

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I installed `sbt-1.3.4.msi` and when trying to build a sample `SparkPi.scala` app, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample>sbt
[info] Loading project definition from C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[error] C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\src\main\scala\SparkPi.scala:3:19: object spark is not a member of package org.apache
[error] import org.apache.spark._
[error]                   ^
[error] C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\src\main\scala\SparkPi.scala:8:20: not found: type SparkConf
[error]     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
[error]                    ^
[error] C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\src\main\scala\SparkPi.scala:9:21: not found: type SparkContext
[error]     val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
[error]                     ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The `SparkPi.scala` file is in `C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\src\main\scala` (as shown in the error messages above).

What am I missing here?

The `C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\sparksample.sbt` file is as follows:

```
name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\project\src\main\scala directory has SparkPi.scala file

That's the problem. You've got the Scala file(s) under `project` directory that's owned by sbt itself (not your sbt-managed Scala project).

Move the `SparkPi.scala` and other Scala files to `C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\src\main\scala`.

Comment: After above fix, it ran without error, but there is no .jar file in C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\target. Instead, I see a file called "out" in C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\target\streams\_global\ivyConfiguration\_global\streams.

Comment: The issue is fixed by changing the sbt file's line to  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0"

Comment: @frosty Thanks for accepting my answer! Much appreciated. As for your "fix", I'd disagree, i.e. `+=` operator is for a single dependency while `++=` is for zero, one or more dependencies. They're equivalent in your case. BTW, You don't need to look at `C:\myapps\sbt\sparksample\target\streams_global` directory since it's internal to sbt (not for users).